# Raster CellSize with valX x valY

Tags: postgis, raster, esri-ascii-raster

Any idea if it is possible to have an esri-asci file with a cellSize with 2 values specified? From what I read is not, but I have one file that is like that and I wader how should I import it in my postGis raster table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would guess you could create 2 separate rasters from the single ascii file. Please check out the tour http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: GDAL is writing DX and DY is such case http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html. Probably it can read those as well but I am not sure what to do next. Perhaps write an interim GeoTIFF before entering PostGIS raster.

Answer (score 1):

The standard ESRI specification assumes square cells, so correct usage precludes differing X and Y cellsizes.  However, GDAL can write to a file that is ***like*** an ESRI ASCII grid with DX and DY sizes.  This can be read by only a limited number of applications (being non-standard) like Golden Surfer.  Just because GDAL can, doesn't mean you should.  That said, because GDAL can handle this, then I would recommend using GDAL translate to import the file in question into PostGIS (should be no need for an intermediary).

If you want non-square pixels and also want the output to be usable in most GIS applications, I would avoid ESRI's ASCII format for this reason.  In fact, I would avoid the ESRI ASCII format for all but the most specific interoperability cases where a GeoTiff is not acceptable and an ESRI ASCII is required.